# Jquery multiple contains operators with or

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, comparison

We have a Jquery code on our SharePoint site that retrieves all data from a table based on user input into a text box.  We're trying to implement buttons that act as a set of filters to help tighten the user's search.

I think my main problem here is that i'm having trouble with the Jquery comparison operator syntax.  Here's the main line of code that's the culprit ;

```
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:not(:contains("+txt+"):contains("+ButtonValue+")').hide();
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:contains("+txt+"):contains("+ButtonValue+")').show();
```

essentially just looking for it it to retrieve the contents that are similar to the buttons' value and the search query.  Or one or the other.  Here's the rest of the code to help put things into context.

Note: In the .click function i've ommitted a lot of code because it's just a bunch of repetitive spaghetti code at the moment.  But this gives you the gist of how the relationship between the two functions works.

```
var ButtonValue = ""
$("#button1").click(function(){


          $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();            

         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

        $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

        $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

        $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show();

        $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains('Faucets'))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains('Faucets')").show()
         ButtonValue = "Faucets" 

         });

var txt = ""
$("input.search").change(function() {
          var txt = $("input.search").val();
          alert(txt)

    if (txt) {
          //alert("VN : " + VN);
          //alert(".change() called");

         //Vendor List
         $("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:not(:contains("+txt+"):contains("+ButtonValue+")').hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:contains("+txt+"):contains("+ButtonValue+")').show();

         //Manufacturer Reps
         // Logic to see search value is numeric then search using the company name
         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();

         //Vendor Contact List
         $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();

         //Vendor Document List
         $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();

         // Vendor Details
         $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();

         // Product Lines
         $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").hide();
         $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover:Contains("+txt+")").show();

        } else {

          $("#WebPartWPQ6").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
          $("#WebPartWPQ7").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
          $("#WebPartWPQ4").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
          $("#WebPartWPQ8").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
          $("#WebPartWPQ2").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
          $("#WebPartWPQ5").find("tr.ms-itmhover").show();           
        }
      }).keyup(function(){$(this).change();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax on those lines are incorrect

```
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:not(:contains("'+txt+'"):contains("'+ButtonValue+'")').hide();
$("#WebPartWPQ5").find('tr.ms-itmhover:contains("'+txt+'"):contains("'+ButtonValue+'")').show();
```

Comment: How would I do this so that it looks for both the txt and ButtonValue variables? I believe that presently it is looking for either one, and since I have a query that is returning with all the values from button variable, it is not making their search more specific when the user types into the txt input.